# How to read number of terms in the index created by whoosh library in python?

Tags: whoosh

The whoosh library automatically creates 3 files after the commit operation and I am not able to find any way to read the seg file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find any way to read the seg file but I found this [Whoosh reading package](http://whoosh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/reading.html) which contains methods to read the contents of the index